# Do Atom have an option to display where the element started?

Tags: atom-editor, code-editor

I'm not a native speaker and I'd happy if someone can edit my question title to make it sound more English!

What I'm looking for in Atom is a feature of the JetBrains editor which allows you to see where a given code element has been started by doing an overflow in the current code.

Like this:

[image: What I'm talking about]

I'm missing this feature for the edition of big complicated html files and I'm sure it exists but I cannot find a name for it and it doesn't seem to be included as-is.

Do someone know where I can find it?

Comment: if you put your curser on the end } it underlines it.  if you scroll up the matching { is underlined too.  I don't know of a add on that draws the lines like you are showing, but I'm sure there could be one.  Or press ctrl-M and it will go between the two matching brackets

Comment: Yeah I knew that but I would really need this overlying stuff to keep my ideas clear. Anyway, till I find the solution, I'll stay with Webstorm